# AJAX update every input on textfield word counter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax jquery and php for my program. I want to display every word I type in the textfield to look like this:

if I typed "this is is a sample sample word word word", the output should be like:

```
//output
This = 1
is = 2
a = 1
sample = 2
word = 3
//end_output
```

My current code only displays what I have typed on the textbox and returns it.
 index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Working with Javascript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="input" id="textInput" autofocus/>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
        var jTextInput = $("#textInput");
        var divSelector = document.getElementById("content");
        textInput.onkeyup = function () {
            console.log($("#textInput").val());
            $.ajax({
                "method": "POST", //to specify what type of METHOD to 
 REQUEST in the SERVER (GET or POST)
                "url": "assigned.php", // where to send the request
                "dataType": "JSON", // datatype of the request
                "data": {
                    "text": $("#textInput").val()
                }, //DATA values that you'll sebd
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#content").html(res.reversedString);
                }
            });
        };
    </script>    
</html>
```

and the other page is assigned.php

```
<?php

$var = array("reversedString" => $_POST['text']);

echo json_encode($var);
?>
```

I have an idea for php and it look like this

```
    $text = $_POST['input'];
    $words = explode(' ', $text);
    sort($words);
    $result = array_combine($words, array_fill(0, count($words), 0));
    $len = count($words);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
        echo $words[$i] . " ";
    }echo "<br> <br>";

    foreach ($words as $word) {
        $result[$word] ++;
    }

    foreach ($result as $word => $count) {
        echo "$word = $count<br>";
    }
```

but I have no idea where to put it and how will it work and if it does work or not. I prefer to put it on the assigned.php. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you just need simply put those code in `assigned.php` and it will be sent as plain text, then front-end can get them and append it into html.

But more possible in web develop data will be transmitted as JSON between front-end and back-end, and the mission to parse data is belongs to front-end. So you can consider changing the way to return JSON data at PHP. If you want to send JSON in php just set header like `header('content-type: application/json')`

Comment: Thank you for the information mate. I cannot fully understand what you mean as I am new to ajax, but a fiddle is very much appreciated.